# Мобильный лендинг

Tags: css3, html, html5, css

Добрый день! Как лучше делать мобильный лендинг, с помощью программ или с помощью медиа запроов? Первый раз столкнулся с этим.

Comment: без програм вы точно не обойдетесь :)

Comment: @eicto, посоветуйте пожалуйста программу, ну и статьи хорошие об этом, а то поискал не очень уж понятно, буду очень благодарен:)

Comment: ну google-chrome например :) у вас вопрос слишком общий, все зависит от того что вы хотите сделать, какое у вас приложение итд.

Comment: @eicto,Вот: Простой мобильный лендинг наподобие
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7739475/temp/maket.gif
необходимо, чтобы страница выглядела в стандартном андроид-стиле
http://1-tn.com/tools/lands/br/wts/es/7%20-%20expire-syst-01/index%20copy.php однако очень важные моменты - чтобы подобный лендинг был максимально компактен
(все минимизировано, иконки в один ресурс через спрайт, итп.)Вот так попросили меня:)